# New JFrame Being Created When I Add Content Pane

Tags: java, jframe

I don't know why but when I add a content pane it creates a new JFrame window instead of replacing the old content pane on the same window. Thank you, my code follows below: I have a `public void` (container pane). This is what I'm adding to the JFrame.

```
public  void Start1(){       

    if (number==0){

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Set up the content pane.
    add(getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
    pack();
    setVisible(true); 
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

    setVisible(true);
}
    else {
      add(getContentPane());

    //Display the window.
        pack();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more code? The constructor of your JFrame would be helpful. Where is this `void Start1` in your class? From where is it being called? I'm pretty sure you're just missing a `this.close()` somewhere. And in addition, why are you creating a Content Pane? Every JFrame comes with one, you only add components to it.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a content pane to your frame? Every JFrame already has a content pane, and you add components to that content pane. What is it you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: basically the file is called Frametemplate and it extends JFrame

Comment: i am trying to replace the old content pane with a new one insted off a new jframe which is what is happening

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the old content pane? What are you trying to achieve with this solution?

Comment: updating the content pane as the contents change

Comment: You don't need to delete the content pane and recreate it to do so. You can achieve your goal by changing the components. Even the Content Pane properties, if you want. But I don't see any advantage in recreating the content pane.

Comment: i have a container which has components which change so the content pane needs updating when the container's components change

Comment: This is the classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You want to clear the contents of the frame? Try `removeAll()`. There's no need to mess with the content pane. It's like replacing the interior of your car to get the passengers to leave.  If you're just trying to update, try removing and adding components and then doing `revalidate()` and `repaint()`. Please take the time to read the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) on building GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the problem you're facing with updating the contents of your `ContentPane` a simple `removeAll();` and then `repaint();` would be enought. A Content Pane is always created with it's JFrame, and should not be removed if you have other options. In your case, you should only update your Content Pane's components. This is a solution I made up when I faced a similar problem:

I had a JPanel created in my Content Pane:

```
JPanel viewport = new JPanel();
viewport.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
viewport.setBounds(0, 302, 414, 420);
contentPane.add(viewport);
viewport.setLayout(null);
```

And then, whenever I wanted to update that screen, I added the following code to the method/event:

```
viewport.removeAll();
viewport.repaint();
```

This will remove every component you had and repaint it to your JPanel. So if you update the information (or whatever it is you want to update) and then run these two simple methods, you'll have your components properly updated.

If you have any other doubts, feel to check [the class](https://github.com/Pelicer/eaicomeu/blob/master/src/view/usuario/pedido/ViewEntrega.java) in which I implemented this solution in my GitHub.